# Does a custom DataGridView Cell have to have a parameterless constructor?

Tags: .net, datagridview

I want a slight variation of the custom cell example from the MS website

[How to: Customize Cells and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control by Extending Their Behavior and Appearance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx)

by passing an argument to the custom cell constructor so I could use it later, namely to evaluate something when painting the cell.

`Private _o as MyObject`
`Public Sub New(ByVal o As MyObject)`
`MyBase.New()`
`_o = o`
`End Sub`

but then when I run the code it throws and exception

MissingMethodException occured
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Does this mean that custom cells must have a parameterless constructor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*At a guess*, the table is going to use reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance`) to create instances of the cell on a per-row basis; so yes - it will need a public parameterless constructor to do that.